# vue.jsでfirebaseのデータベースの変更にもリアクティブに反応させられるものでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase

firebaseのリアルタイムデータベース上のデータの変更に応じて、リストレンダリングをしたいのですが、表示されません。（画像A）
`members`オブジェクトをローカルでつくって読み込むとうまく表示され、入力するとオブジェクトが更新されるのですが。（画像B）

（画像A）

[image: 1]

（画像B）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
画像Bの方には、「reactiveGetter」などが付いているようです。

また

```
app.$forceUpdate();
```

としてみたのですが、だめです。

```
 <div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="m in members">
                <input type="text" v-model:value="m.name">
                <input type="text" v-model:value="m.state">
                <input type="text" v-model:value="m.dest">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        let app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                members: []
            },
            methods: {
                setWatcher: function ()
                {
                    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userID + '/members');
                    ref.on('value', function (snapshot)
                    {
                        this.members = snapshot.val();
                        console.log(members); // ログにArrayが表示される
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　 app.$forceUpdate(); // 効かない模様
                    });
                }
            },
            created: function ()
            {
                this.setWatcher();
            }
        }) 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コールバックでのthis束縛が原因でしたら、setWatcher内で一旦`const self = this;`のように変数に保存しておいてコールバックでは`self.message = ...`のようにするか、モダンブラウザを使える場合はアロー関数にするかします。

```js
                setWatcher: function ()
                {
                    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userID + '/members');
                    ref.on('value', (snapshot) =>
                    {
                        this.members = snapshot.val();
                        console.log(members);
 　 　　　　　　　　　　　app.$forceUpdate();
                    });
                }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！すごいです！できました！アロー関数だと変わるのですね！

Comment: アロー関数だと何が違うのですか？

Comment: JavaScriptの通常の関数内でのthisは関数の呼び出し方によって変わりますが、アロー関数内のthisはレキシカルスコープになりsetWatcherのthisと同じになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！それぞれのthisをログに出して調べればいいですね。